# How to see pip installation details while installing a conda environment using a YAML file?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to debug a problem with conda environment not being able to install pip dependencies, but `conda create env -f environment.yaml` is not very helping with the output of its pip transactions, this is how it is trying to install pip dependencies.

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Installing pip dependencies: \
```

Is there any way to get a detailed output of what is happening inside `pip install` in a yaml file?

Comment: Have you tried the verbose option of `conda`?

Comment: Try setting (and exporting) `PIP_VERBOSE=3` [environment variable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables) before running `conda`.

Comment: Apparently there's an ongoing issue with how conda executes subprocesses. I have left a comment here to see what happens. https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10556

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of [direct Conda support](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10556) for `pip install` verbosity, one could manually debug by splitting the YAML. That is, separate the YAML requirements into a Conda-only version and take all the `pip:` requirements and put them in a `requirements.txt`. Create the environment from the Conda-only YAML, activate it, then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` using whatever level of verbosity you need.

Comment: The problem with this is that this makes my conda installation a bit platform specific. I'm currently using conda to install pytorch + related dependencies in a very platform agnostic manner, and adding a bashscript for example to automate a pip dependency seems like a bit of a hassle and less maintainable.

Comment: Oh, I was only suggesting this for debugging. I agree this wouldn't be a good strategy for production installation.